# what does it mean of when the going's tough?

Tags: meaning

When I heard a song I saw the following lyrics.

> I just wanna love you when the going's tough

My first question is what "going's" stand for?
I think "going's" might be "going is"

The second question is what meaning of going include?
Can you let me know another example sentence with going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context "going's" is in reference to the current series of events.

For example, if we were to hike up a particularly hard route, you could say, "Wow, the going's tough."

Mostly popularised by the song by Billy Ocean - When the going gets tough, the tough get going.

Using a play on the two separate meanings of each of these.

The first being, when one encounters a series of difficulties.
The second being, the tough individuals then get moving to solve these difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "when the going is tough."

Use this definition of "going"

> 2.2 Conditions for, or progress in, an endeavour.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/going)

Perhaps the "endeavor" meant in that song is the relationship between the singer and the person addressed by the singer.